# MySQL reordering list table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL workbench I have a list table of the following format:

```
ID  | type | order | time
----|------|-------|----------
id1 |  1   |  1    | 2017-1-1
id1 |  2   |  2    | 2017-1-2
id1 |  1   |  3    | 2017-1-4
id1 |  2   |  4    | 2017-1-5
id2 |  1   |  1    | 2017-1-1
id2 |  2   |  2    | 2017-1-9
id3 |  1   |  1    | 2017-1-1
id3 |  2   |  2    | 2017-1-2
id3 |  1   |  3    | 2017-1-9
id3 |  2   |  4    | 2017-1-11
id3 |  1   |  5    | 2017-1-13
id3 |  2   |  6    | 2017-1-18
```

I would like to reorder the table to give the following output:

```
ID  |  time(1)  | time(2)
----|-----------|-----------
id1 | 2017-1-1  | 2017-1-2
id1 | 2017-1-4  | 2017-1-5 
id2 | 2017-1-1  | 2017-1-9
id3 | 2017-1-1  | 2017-1-2
id3 | 2017-1-9  | 2017-1-11
id3 | 2017-1-13 | 2017-1-18
```

I have a solution for the above but it seems to take ages when fetching the results on a half million entries table. I was wondering if anybody could offer a solution to the above problem that I could try.

Thanks for your help,Luca

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.ID, t1.time as 'time(1)', t2.time as 'time(2)'
from Table1 t1 join Table1 t2
on t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.type=1 and t2.type=2
and t1.order=t2.order-1 and t2.order%2=0;

|  ID |   time(1) |   time(2) |
|-----|-----------|-----------|
| id1 |  2017-1-1 |  2017-1-2 |
| id1 |  2017-1-4 |  2017-1-5 |
| id2 |  2017-1-1 |  2017-1-9 |
| id3 |  2017-1-1 |  2017-1-2 |
| id3 |  2017-1-9 | 2017-1-11 |
| id3 | 2017-1-13 | 2017-1-18 |
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works much better than what I had. Luca